# how to delete a file in s3 via lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am able to copy a file from one bucket to another, but not sure if i'm doing this wrong but i can't delete the file . any thoughts?

```
import boto3
import os
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
aws4auth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,credentials.secret_key,region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
                    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

s3.meta.client.copy({'Bucket': name, 'key': key}, targetBucket, key)
s3.meta.client.delete({{'Bucket': name, 'key': key}})
```

Comment: Any errors or timeouts?

Comment: marcin - it complains that it doesn't recognize the delete function.

Comment: `delete` is a method on `Object` object, like in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`, you may use it to delete the object.

For this you would create [Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) and then used its [delete](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.delete) method. For example:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

object_to_be_deleted = s3.Object(name, key)

object_to_be_deleted.delete()
```

Also since you are using lambda, make sure that your function's **execution role** has permissions to delete the object or there are no bucket policies which prohibit such an action.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `boto3 client()` rather than `resource()`. Anyways, here is what I tried and worked for me:

**To copy file**

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('s3')
copy_source = {'Bucket': 'from-bucket-s3', 'Key': 'cfn.json'}
client.copy(copy_source, 'to-bucket-s3', 'other-cfn.json')
```

**To delete file**

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client('s3')

client.delete_object(Bucket='to-bucket-s3', Key='other-cfn.json')
```

boto3 client() supports vast number of APIs than resource()